# JS GeoLocation: make $.ajax wait for result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I send an AJAX POST request to my back-end, I want to send the latitude and longitude from navigator. But apparently, on the background, the request is being sent without even waiting for the navigator to finish.
I am using the Parse library, is there a way I can put the request on hold until the lat/lon has been collected?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Parse.initialize("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
    var Location = Parse.Object.extend("Location");
    var location = new Location();
    location.save({
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        description: "Testdescription",
        kind: 1
    }).then(function(object){
        alert("YAY, it worked.");
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to break it up. When the call comes back, submit the form.

Comment: Please show us relevant example code -- it's really hard to debug code without seeing it! :)

Comment: So can I attach an event to the result of executing the function?

Like function.on('done', callbackToSend);?

Comment: Added code for example.
I want the `location.save()` to execute AFTER lat/lon have been collected

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calll your ajax request in location success callback as below:

function geolocationSucess(position)
{
  // call your method to save data
}